# How to navigate through a dynamic created link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a table in HTML which gets filled dynamically with `<td>` elements. These elements are a link, but I don't know how to navigate through them.

My HTML:

```
<div id="catalog-page" data-role="page">
        <!-- catalog header -->
        <div data-role="header" data-id="header" id="catalog-header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-header">
            <a href="#home-page" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            <h1>Pokémon Catalog</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /catalog header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>Gotta catch em all!</h1>


            <table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">

                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>
```

My JS file:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#catalog-page", function() {
console.warn("catalog-page loaded");
$.ajax({
    url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
}).then(function(data) {
    console.warn("Found " + data.count + " pokemon...");
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(data.results));

    var obj = data.results;
    drawTable(obj);

    function drawTable(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i], i);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData, c) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#table-column-toggle").append(row);
        row.append($("<td><a href=#pokemon"+c +">" + rowData.name + "</a></td>"));
    }

});
});
```

The results of this will be like:

[image]

Bulbasaur will have an id of pokemon0, ivysaur pokemon1, etc..

The problem is that if I click on Bulbasaur, I want the page to load a new div. In this div I want to provide information about the Bulbasaur. I am using Jquery mobile for the dynamic loading of the div.

In my HTML code:

```
<div id="pokemon0" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-id="header" id="catalog-header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-header">
            <a href="#catalog-page" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            <h1>Here comes the name of the pokemon</h1>

        </div>
</div>
```

This works, but as you can see, I've written id="pokemon0", but that is not how I want it because otherwise I have to create 811 div's..

So long story short, is there a way to change id="pokemon0" to whatever link I am clicking (for instance id="pokemon12")?

Comment: Could you add the JS code you have associated with the `<div>`?

Comment: Use `.load()` to load the description dynamically using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one div with generic id

```
<div id="pokemon" data-role="page">
```

Add click handler to your dynamic links

```
$("a[href^='#pokemon']").click(function(){
  $('#pokemon h1').html($(this).text());
});
```

See working example [here](https://jsbin.com/reyifafori/edit?html,js,output). By the way, it takes a long time to create 811 table rows.